# Centering alt text in JS gallery

Tags: javascript, html, css, image-gallery, alt

I have an image gallery that opens each image, below the image grid, as an enlargement with descriptive text. I can't seem to get the text to center and stay on the image. I have tried changing the CSS with overflow, width, etc., but I think it's in the JS code. I do not know JS, I found the code on a codepen and made changes as needed (and with some stack overflow help!). In addition, I would like the enlarged image to close and revert back to the gallery after a period of time. Is that possible?

The link to my codepen is https://codepen.io/Ovimel/pen/YgzVeg  The first image shows the issue I am having.

I'm a coding novice, and I'm not sure that I posted the code here correctly. Actually, I know it's not correct as the images are not aligned and standard sizes and the enlargements don't load, but do I need to post everything? The codepen is where you'll see it actually work/not work. Thanks in advance for your help!

```css
/*styling for gallery page images*/

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/*The grid: Four equal columns that floats next to each other */

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/*Style the images inside the grid */

.column img {
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.column img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* The expanding image container */

.container-gallerypage {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Expanding image text */

#imgtext {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 35px;
  color: red;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Closable button inside the expanded image */

.closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*styling for footer and footer text links*/

footer {
  background-color: #6e6b5c;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Days One", sans-serif;
  font-size: .8em;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 3px #194a76;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}


/*@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .footer {
    background-image: url(https://kehilalinks.jewishgen.org/images/KehilaLinksLogo.transparent.png);
  }
}*/

a.footerlinks {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.footerlinks:link,
a.footerlinks:visited {
  color: white;
}

a.footerlinks:hover,
a.footerlinks:active {
  color: #194a76;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<article role="main">
  <header>
    <h1>THE GALLERY</h1>
    <p style="font-style: italic; text-align: center;">Click on an image to read the caption and to view a larger version below.</p>
  </header>


  <!-- slide gallery -->
  <!-- The four columns -->

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://kehilalinks.jewishgen.org/Stavishche/images/20.jpg" alt="The Eli Lechtzer Family, circa 1915. (L - R, seated) Chana Butzarsky Lechtzer, Raizel (Rose) Lechtzer, Eli Lechtzer, and Golda Lechtzer (standing). If there is lots of text for an image how do I keep it within the image or have it offset to the right side and keep the image on the left side. If there is lots of text for an image how do I keep it within the image or have it offset to the right side and keep the image on the left side.
    " style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://kehilalinks.jewishgen.org/Stavishche/images/2.jpg" alt="Sisters of Stavisht" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://kehilalinks.jewishgen.org/Stavishche/images/6.jpg" alt="Four girls" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://kehilalinks.jewishgen.org/Stavishche/images/22.jpg" alt="Raizel Lechtzer,  circa 1917. Raizel, wearing her school uniform, is about 7 years old in this photo." style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://kehilalinks.jewishgen.org/Stavishche/images/20.jpg" alt="The Eli Lechtzer Family, circa 1915. (L - R, seated) Chana Butzarsky Lechtzer, Raizel (Rose) Lechtzer, Eli Lechtzer, and Golda Lechtzer (standing). 
    " style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://kehilalinks.jewishgen.org/Stavishche/images/2.jpg" alt="Sisters of Stavisht" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://kehilalinks.jewishgen.org/Stavishche/images/6.jpg" alt="Four girls" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://kehilalinks.jewishgen.org/Stavishche/images/22.jpg" alt="Raizel Lechtzer,  circa 1917. Raizel, wearing her school uniform, is about 7 years old in this photo." style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="container-gallerypage">
    <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn">&times;</span>
    <img id="expandedImg" style="width:80%">
    <div id="imgtext" style="text-align: center;width:100%;"></div>
  </div>

</article>

<br>

<!-- Footer -->
<footer id="footerlogo" role="contentinfo">
  <p>This site is hosted at no cost to the public by
    <a class="footerlinks" href="https://jewishgen.org">JewishGen, Inc.</a>, a non-profit corporation. If you feel there is a benefit to you in accessing this site, please consider supporting our important work through
    <a class="footerlinks" href="https://jewishgen.org/JewishGen-erosity">JewishGen-erosity</a>. Visit the
    <a class="footerlinks" href="https://kehilalinks.jewishgen.org">JewishGen KehilaLinks</a> website to discover other communities.</p>
  <p>Copyright &copy;2012-2019. All rights reserved. Design and website by Vivian Linderman.
    <address>
            <a class="footerlinks" href="mailto:vivian_lbdn@hotmail.com">CONTACT WEBMASTER</a>
          </address>Created 2012, updated 2019.
  </p>
</footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd personally start the whole thing again, but adding this to your CSS should help

```
#imgtext {
    width: 70%;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 100px;
}
```

I just tested in the code pen and it requires the !important tag

```
#imgtext {
    width: 70%!important;
    display: block!important;
    margin: auto!important;
    position: relative!important;
    bottom: 100px!important;
}
```

Comment: This definitely works to center the text, but the longer text still pours over the bottom of the photo. I changed the bottom: 100px; to 200px; which fixed that on the longer text, but then for the images that had a few words, it brought the text up too high. Also, on smaller screens, text overflows at the bottom of the images. I played with margins, position, and bottom to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

A small tweak of your css can give the desired result. Set a `max-width` (narrower than the full width) and a margin that will set it appropriately (in this case I gave it a max width of 75% and a margin left and right of 10% [an approximation, taking into account browser-added margins/padding], and set it to `display:block` with `position:absolute`, 20% from the top. Any of these values can be tweaked as you wish, but you get the picture. I would recommend using a smaller font size for benefit of smaller screens, by the by

Hope this helps

```js
//Make older browsers aware of new HTML5 layout tags 
'header nav aside article footer section'.replace(/\w+/g, function(n) {
  document.createElement(n)
})

function myFunction(imgs) {
  var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
  var imgText = document.getElementById("imgtext");
  expandImg.src = imgs.src;
  imgText.innerHTML = imgs.alt;
  expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
/*styling for gallery page images*/

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/*The grid: Four equal columns that floats next to each other */

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/*Style the images inside the grid */

.column img {
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.column img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* The expanding image container */

.container-gallerypage {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Expanding image text */

#imgtext {
  display: block;
  max-width:75%;
  position: absolute;
  top:20%;
  text-align:center;
  margin:0 10%;
  color: red;
  font-size: 20px;
}


/* Closable button inside the expanded image */

.closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*styling for footer and footer text links*/

footer {
  background-color: #6e6b5c;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Days One", sans-serif;
  font-size: .8em;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 3px #194a76;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}


/*@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .footer {
    background-image: url(https://kehilalinks.jewishgen.org/images/KehilaLinksLogo.transparent.png);
  }
}*/

a.footerlinks {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.footerlinks:link,
a.footerlinks:visited {
  color: white;
}

a.footerlinks:hover,
a.footerlinks:active {
  color: #194a76;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<body>
<article role="main">
  <header>
    <h1>THE GALLERY</h1>
    <p style="font-style: italic; text-align: center;">Click on an image to read the caption and to view a larger version below.</p>
  </header>


  <!-- slide gallery -->
  <!-- The four columns -->

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://kehilalinks.jewishgen.org/Stavishche/images/20.jpg" alt="The Eli Lechtzer Family, circa 1915. (L - R, seated) Chana Butzarsky Lechtzer, Raizel (Rose) Lechtzer, Eli Lechtzer, and Golda Lechtzer (standing). If there is lots of text for an image how do I keep it within the image or have it offset to the right side and keep the image on the left side. If there is lots of text for an image how do I keep it within the image or have it offset to the right side and keep the image on the left side.
    " style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://kehilalinks.jewishgen.org/Stavishche/images/2.jpg" alt="Sisters of Stavisht" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://kehilalinks.jewishgen.org/Stavishche/images/6.jpg" alt="Four girls" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://kehilalinks.jewishgen.org/Stavishche/images/22.jpg" alt="Raizel Lechtzer,  circa 1917. Raizel, wearing her school uniform, is about 7 years old in this photo." style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://kehilalinks.jewishgen.org/Stavishche/images/20.jpg" alt="The Eli Lechtzer Family, circa 1915. (L - R, seated) Chana Butzarsky Lechtzer, Raizel (Rose) Lechtzer, Eli Lechtzer, and Golda Lechtzer (standing). 
    " style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://kehilalinks.jewishgen.org/Stavishche/images/2.jpg" alt="Sisters of Stavisht" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://kehilalinks.jewishgen.org/Stavishche/images/6.jpg" alt="Four girls" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://kehilalinks.jewishgen.org/Stavishche/images/22.jpg" alt="Raizel Lechtzer,  circa 1917. Raizel, wearing her school uniform, is about 7 years old in this photo." style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="container-gallerypage">
    <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn">&times;</span>
    <img id="expandedImg" style="width:80%">
    <div id="imgtext" style="text-align: center;width:100%;"></div>
  </div>

</article>

<br>

<!-- Footer -->
<footer id="footerlogo" role="contentinfo">
  <p>This site is hosted at no cost to the public by
    <a class="footerlinks" href="https://jewishgen.org">JewishGen, Inc.</a>, a non-profit corporation. If you feel there is a benefit to you in accessing this site, please consider supporting our important work through
    <a class="footerlinks" href="https://jewishgen.org/JewishGen-erosity">JewishGen-erosity</a>. Visit the
    <a class="footerlinks" href="https://kehilalinks.jewishgen.org">JewishGen KehilaLinks</a> website to discover other communities.</p>
  <p>Copyright &copy;2012-2019. All rights reserved. Design and website by Vivian Linderman.
    <address>
            <a class="footerlinks" href="mailto:vivian_lbdn@hotmail.com">CONTACT WEBMASTER</a>
          </address>Created 2012, updated 2019.
</footer>
</body>
```

Comment: This does help to center the text, but like the other suggestion the text does overflow when the screen size is smaller. I've been playing with adjustments, but need to head out to work. So will revisit later today. I'm using a large sized font because the primary audience for this page tends to be older and not very tech savvy to know how to enlarge the page.

Comment: @Ovimel Write media queries to handle smaller screen sizes. (Of course 20pt font will overflow!!). You only asked about centering the text, and this is not a code writing service, just a helping hand. Good luck

Comment: Thanks @RachelGallen, I'll revisit the media queries in other places in my code.